# The name 'binarySearchRecursive' does not exist in the current context (c#)

Tags: c#, methods, scope

I am writing this function, however it gives me: `The name 'binarySearchRecursive' does not exist in the current context`. I dont understand why i am getting this message, the call is done in the scope of this method itself? Or do i misunderstand a fundamental part of c#?

```
  public static int binarySearchRecusive<T>(T[] a, int low, int high, T v) where T : IComparable
    {    

        if (low < high)
        {
            var middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if (a[middle].CompareTo(v) == 0)
                return middle;
            if (a[middle].CompareTo(v) < 0)
                return binarySearchRecursive(a, low, middle - 1, v);
            else
                return binarySearchRecursive(a, middle+1, high - 1, v);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function goes by this name:

```
binarySearchRecusive
```

If you change it to:

```
binarySearchRecursive
```

it will work.

Comment: oh DAMN a typo. Didnt see it. thank you!

Comment: @user3660293 no problem, I am glad that I could help. Could you please mark this as the answer?

Comment: i will do it as soon as it allows me to ( few mins)

Comment: @user3660293 thank you! I did not know that there was a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Typpo in `binarySearchRecusive`, instead, try `binarySearchRecursive`.
If it still don't work then try `Program.binarySearchRecursive()`